# Update cluster stackdriver version in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

[image: I have this situation]

I have this situation with my kubernetes cluster and I would like to rollback to the stable version of the google cloud, anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: What is that output sample from?

Comment: I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

This is the new logging and monitoring option described at https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/

As far as I know there isn't a downgrade option. If you create a new cluster, you can choose which logging/monitoring integration to use.

Comment: well the issue is, with this V2 beta my cluster doesn't show up in the stackdriver logging, so basically i can't see the logs of it that's why i wanna roll back

Comment: You're aware that the 'resource type' is different? The logs may be hiding under a different drop-down menu option. https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#resource_type_changes